# How can I calculate the dimensions of the current region in react-native-maps?

Tags: google-maps, react-native, maps, react-native-maps

```
latitude: 38.69444432847513
latitudeDelta: 0.1288559458782288
longitude: -90.5969550254043
longitudeDelta: 0.1638044205986091
```

Suppose my map region has the data above (I use onRegionChange)

How can I get the distance (diameter) of the current region, in kilometers?  (the width will be smaller than the height, because the phone is in portrait mode)

Is there an easy conversion I can do?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the "distance" part? Do you want to calculate distance to a different point or distance between the corners of the screen? Direct distance or distance by roads?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Definition of latitudeDelta](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcoordinatespan/1452417-latitudedelta):

> The amount of north-to-south distance (measured in degrees)

Hence you can simply multiply `latitudeDelta` by [`111`](https://www.thoughtco.com/degree-of-latitude-and-longitude-distance-4070616) to get the approximate height (which should be the diameter if height > width).

If you need the width, the formula is slightly more complicated as it's dependent on the latitude:

```
longitudeDelta * 40075 * cos(latitude) / 360
```

If you need a very precise value of the diameter, you can use the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) or [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae), which you can implement yourself or use an npm module.
The two points for the formula will be `(latitude - latitudeDelta / 2, longitude)` and `(latitude + latitudeDelta / 2, longitude)`.

Comment: If I simply multiply the latitudeDelta by 111, will the result be in kilometers?

Comment: Yes. Earth is not perfectly spherical though so the range varies from 110.5 to 111.7, hence your computed value might be off by up to ~0.5%.

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs a very precise value. Here's the [Haversine's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) implementation:

```
const EARTH_RADIUS = 6371000;
const { latitude, longitude, latitudeDelta } = region;

const lat = latitude * Math.PI / 180;
const latDelta = latitudeDelta * Math.PI / 180;

const diameterKm = 2 * EARTH_RADIUS * Math.atan(Math.tan(latDelta / 2) * Math.cos(lat)) / 1000;
const radius = Math.abs(Math.round(diameterKm / 2));
```